# Creating a to do list using (Bootstrap) HTML and pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting started with Javascript and need a little help with creating a simple to do list. I have seen a few questions about this kind of thing on Stack Overflow, but most of them use JQuery or a very different approach than I have taken.
The code successfully takes the input value and dynamically creates content from it, and it also toggles a 'complete' CSS class on-click.
The issue I'm having is that instead of creating a new li for each input task, it will create a new li the first time and then add the new tasks to that li.

```
  (function() { //IIFE
  // DOM queries
    var item = document.getElementById("input").value; //list item input
    var ul = document.getElementById("task-list"); //task list container
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = "list-group-item"; //list item created and assigned class
    var button = document.getElementById("button") //add item button

    // event listeners
    // add task on button click
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){ //create new list item
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //get input from form
      ul.appendChild(li); //attach task to list
      console.log('clicked');
    }, false);

    // toggle task complete on item click
    li.onclick = function(){
      console.log('toggle task completion');
      li.classList.toggle('complete');
    }

}()); //IIFE ENDS
```

How can I create a new li each time instead of just appending new tasks to the first li created? I'm sure it's a simple fix, I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `li` and the event listener for each `li` inside the button click listener:

```js
// DOM queries
var item = document.getElementById("input").value; //list item input
var ul = document.getElementById("task-list"); //task list container
var button = document.getElementById("button") //add item button
// event listeners
// add task on button click
button.addEventListener('click', function() { //create new list item
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = "list-group-item"; //list item created and assigned class
  li.textContent = input.value;
  ul.appendChild(li); //attach task to list 
  // toggle task complete on item click
  li.onclick = function() {
    console.log('toggle task completion');
    li.classList.toggle('complete');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.complete { color: green }
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="button">add</div>
<ul id="task-list"></ul>
```

Though it might be nicer to have only a single listener on the `ul`, using event delegation, rather than adding another listener each time an item is added:

```js
// DOM queries
var item = document.getElementById("input").value; //list item input
var ul = document.getElementById("task-list"); //task list container
var button = document.getElementById("button") //add item button
// event listeners
// add task on button click
button.addEventListener('click', function() { //create new list item
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = "list-group-item"; //list item created and assigned class
  li.textContent = input.value;
  ul.appendChild(li); //attach task to list 
}, false);
ul.onclick = (e) => {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'LI') return;
  // toggle task complete on item click
  console.log('toggle task completion');
  e.target.classList.toggle('complete');
};
```

```css
.complete { color: green }
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="button">add</div>
<ul id="task-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put everything that creates the `li` into the onclick handler:

```
(function() { //IIFE
  // DOM queries
    var item = document.getElementById("input").value; //list item input
    var ul = document.getElementById("task-list"); //task list container
    var button = document.getElementById("button") //add item button

    // event listeners
    // add task on button click
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){ //create new list item
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = "list-group-item"; //list item created and assigned class
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //get input from form
      li.onclick = function(){
        console.log('toggle task completion');
        li.classList.toggle('complete');
      }
      ul.appendChild(li); //attach task to list
      console.log('clicked');
    }, false);

    // toggle task complete on item click


}()); //IIFE ENDS
```

This will make sure that it creates a new `li`-element every time instead of only once

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements are unique once created. You cannot use the same **li**    created to append new **li**. You must create a new **li** every time like this:

```
(function() { //IIFE
    // DOM queries
    var item = document.getElementById("input").value; //list item input
    var ul = document.getElementById("task-list"); //task list container
    //Remove line creating li here
    li.className = "list-group-item"; //list item created and assigned class
    var button = document.getElementById("button") //add item button

    // event listeners
    // add task on button click
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){ //create new list item
        //Placed line here
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value)); //get input from form
        ul.appendChild(li); //attach task to list
        console.log('clicked');
    }, false);

    // toggle task complete on item click
    li.onclick = function(){
    console.log('toggle task completion');
    li.classList.toggle('complete');
    }
}()); //IIFE ENDS
```